# Vertical align using Material UI Paper

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to vertically align some text in a Material UI Paper component.

The code is [here](https://codesandbox.io/embed/material-demo-fz9wj).

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    padding: theme.spacing(3, 2),
    height: 200,
    verticalAlign: 'middle'
  },
}));

function PaperSheet() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div>
      <Paper className={classes.root}>
        <Typography variant="h5" component="h3">
          This is a sheet of paper.
        </Typography>
        <Typography component="p">
          Paper can be used to build surface or other elements for your application.
        </Typography>
      </Paper>
    </div>
  );
}

export default PaperSheet;
```

Answer (score 32):

`vertical-align` CSS property only works with `display: block` element.

An option for you could be to declare your `root` class using flexbox:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    padding: theme.spacing(3, 2),
    height: 200,
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "column",
    justifyContent: "center"
  },
}));
```

Comment: good solution considering material-ui does this internally a lot. Another "hacky" alternative would be to `position: absolute; top: 50%; transform: translateY(-50%);`

Comment: To the [contrary](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align), "Note that vertical-align only applies to inline, inline-block and table-cell elements..."

Answer (score 5):

You can use `Stack` in **MUI v5**. Set the direction to `column` and `justifyContent` to center to center align the content inside the `Card`:

```
<Paper component={Stack} direction="column" justifyContent="center">
  <div>
    This content is vertically aligned
  </div>
</Paper>
```

### Live Demo

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Comment: Doesn't work... even in your CodeSandbox demo...

Comment: @MatthewOakley it works in my codesandbox. What browser are you using. Are you using MUI v5?